# ELMAH IController factory not found - Right way to redirect to Error page - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

Am trying to use `ELMAH with MVC4` and configured using NUGET Package for MVC.

It handles all the exceptions happening in my code and am logging it to SQL Server.

Using the Ajax Error function am handling AJAX Exceptions(500) Error too. Everything works fine and redirected Error page `overriding OnException in Filter Config`

But if the user changes the URL and and if the controller doesnt exist am getting Error and not redirected to the Error page.

Ex:

```
sitename/test -- Correct URL

sitename/tst ---- Getting Server Error instead redirecting to Error page
```

What is the correct way to handle 404 using ELMAH and redirecting to friendly 404 page in MVC.

I tried changing the `Custom Error with 404 in web.config` but it didn't worked as expected.

By default all Errors other than 404 am re directing to Error page

Am trying to redirect to friendly 404 page rather than server error page.

Any useful links or code will be helpful .Thanks

============================================

Update web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On">
<error statusCode="500" redirect="/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml"/>
<error statusCode="404" redirect="/Views/Shared/ErrorNotFound.cshtml"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: `I tried changing the Custom Error with 404 in web.config but it didn't worked as expected`  Post your web.config.  What did it do?  What did you expect it to do?

Comment: try this first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700379/error-pages-not-found-throwing-elmah-error-with-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET MVC, your URL does not represent the View you are displaying.  It is the Controller Action.  You cannot navigate to a View.

For example, the url ~/Home/Index, does not point to `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`.  It points to the `Index` method of `Controllers/HomeController`.  This method then renders the `Index.cshtml` view and returns the result.

So first, you need to create an `ErrorController`.  Then, you need to move your Error Views into a matching `Error` folder.  Now add action methods for `Error` and `ErrorNotFound` to your `ErrorController`, and have them return the correct View.

Finally, change your web.config redirect URL's to `~/Error/ErrorNotFound`.

Using this method, you will probably want to change the names of the Controller Actions, and their respective Views to remove the duplicated work `Error`.